# How to use canvas for node.js on heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, discord

The error I get is the following:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'canvas'
Require stack:
- /app/index.js
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:957:15)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:840:27)at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1019:19)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/app/index.js:6:16)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1133:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1153:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:977:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:877:14)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12) {
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
requireStack: [ '/app/index.js' ]
```

When I tried local it worked fine, I started having problems after I uploaded the code on Heroku. I've searched online but seems like all answers on google for this question are outdated. These are my current dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "canvas": "^2.6.1",
    "discord.js": "^12.2.0",
    "node": "^14.2.0"
}
```

And this is my code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { prefix } = require ('./config.json');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const Canvas = require('canvas');

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});

client.on('message', message => {
    // Do something.
}
```

Anyone that could help with it?

Comment: Does it work in local env? Or just Heroku? How are you implementing it?

Comment: Right, I upgraded my question!

Answer (score 0):

First, with Heroku, you don't need to upload your node_modules on GitHub or something else. You can also try in the terminal :

> npm start

Then :

> npm install discord.js canvas node

If it isn't enough, check in your **package.json** file if there is :

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
}
```

Comment: With `npm start` I get the following:

npm ERR! missing script: start

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/carlobettelini/.npm/_logs/2020-05-20T13_46_37_320Z-debug.log

Comment: Have you started your dyno as npm ?

Comment: There is. Do you have a Procfile ? Are all your settings done (for example in the settings panel, use Node.JS) ?

Comment: Yes and yes, buildpack node.js, Config Vars for token and resources is dino with 'Worker node index.js'.

Comment: In your package.json, do you have something in "scripts" like "start": "node index.js" ? It's the only solution I think with an error like yours

Comment: No, I don't have that. How can I add it?

Comment: I've added that to script, but Heroku still complains that it cannot find module canvas.